# Why do I get TypeError exception in my Python project?

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

I'm doing a practical exercise on Optimization Methods in Python 3.7. Everything works well except for one function.

```
def parabolic(function, a, b, epsilon):
x1 = a
x2 = (a + b) / 2
x3 = b
f1 = function(x1)
f2 = function(x2)
f3 = function(x3)
while x3 - x1 > epsilon:
    u = x2 - 0.5*((f2 - f3)(x2 - x1)**2 - (f2 - f1)(x2 - x3)**2)/((x2 - x1)(f2 - f3) - (x2 - x3)(f2 - f1))
    if f2 < f1 and f2 < f3:
        fu = function(u)
        if f2 < fu:
            x1 = x2
            f1 = f2
        if f2 > fu:
            x3 = x2
            f3 = f2
        if f2 == fu:
            x1 = x2
            x3 = u
            f1 = f2
            f3 = fu
return (x1 + x3) / 2
```

Exception message was

```
  File "F:/PythonProjects/optimization1/main.py", line 103, in parabolic
    u = x2 - 0.5*((f2 - f3)(x2 - x1)**2 - (f2 - f1)(x2 - x3)**2)/((x2 - x1)(f2 - f3) - (x2 - x3)(f2 - f1))
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

I don't have enough experience in Python and really don't know what the problem is. Maybe it's connected with type conversion

Answer (score 1):

In Python `(f2-f1)(x2-x3)` doesn't mean multiply. You have to mention the multiply operator between them.

Updated code

```
u = x2 - 0.5*((f2 - f3)*(x2 - x1)**2 - (f2 - f1)*(x2 - x3)**2)/((x2 - x1)*(f2 - f3) - (x2 - x3)*(f2 - f1))
```